# Keping a column fixed and kmeans cluster the others

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I am fairly new to data analysis. I have a dataframe where one column contains the names, the other columns are the values associated. I want to cluster the names on the basis of the other columns. So, if I have the df like-

`name       cost      mode  estimate_cost`

`0  John  29.049896  1.499571     113.777457`

`1   Foo  39.049896  2.499571     123.777457`

`2   Moo   2.049896  0.499571      11.777457`

I want to do kmeans and it should return like-

Cluster-1: `0  John  29.049896  1.499571     113.777457`

```
       `1   Foo  39.049896  2.499571     123.777457`
```

Cluster-2: `2   Moo   2.049896  0.499571      11.777457`

Could anyone guide me how to do it?

I tried doing k means but can't figure a way without dropping the 'name' column. The clusters are okay but I lose the names each time.